Do I ignore 'How' in a works cited page?
Here is the citation:

“How AI is Expanding the Attack Surface.” ITWeb, 23 Jan 2024,
https://www.itweb.co.za/article/how-ai-is-expanding-the-attack-surface/mYZRXM9gQbovOgA8.
Accessed 17 April 2024.

I know you ignore certain words when sorting a works cited page, such as 'the' or 'a.' Is 'How' one of those words?
Should I move the citation around my works cited page based on the word 'How' or on the word 'AI?'

First of all, you should specify in your question which style guide you follow.
Second, you should give the author of a source and sort sources by author name. In your case the author seems to be CyberArk.
Third, if there is no author, the owner of the website may be given in place of the author (according to both APA and CMOS). In your case the owner of the website is ITWeb.
Fourth, if the source is given by its title alone, only articles ("a", "an", "the") are ignored for alphabetical ordering. In your case, the source would be ordered by "How".
